# How to return 'bit' value in a certain condition?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to validate the most previous record of UserLog table before letting an user input new data onto the table.

For example,

```
User_ID      Login_Time       Logout_Time
215       2013/02/02 08:59  2013/02/02 18:05
215       2013/02/03 08:58  2013/02/03 18:02
215       2013/02/04 08:59       NULL
```

Let's say today's 2013/02/05 and system i want that system shows an error message because the user forgot to Logout yesterday, 2013/02/04. Can i do this all procedure in a single SELECT query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT IFNULL(Logout_Time, 0) AS bit
FROM log
WHERE User_ID = 215
ORDER BY Login_Time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN logout_time IS NULL THEN "you didn't log out" 
         ELSE "you logged out" 
       end AS message 
...
```